# I am unable to store data using ehcache

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache

I am new to caching world and I am trying to implement cache. I want to cache the output of a method which is calling a web service for some data in order to avoid calling the web service again and again for same data. But my cache is not working and my method is calling the web service again and again for the same data.

spring-server.xml

```
   <bean id = "cacheManager" 
class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
<property name ="cacheManager" ref="ehcache"/>
</bean>
<bean id = "ehcache" 
class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
<property name = "configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
<property named = "shared" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

ehcache.xml

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
   updateCheck="true"
   monitoring="autodetect"
   dynamicConfig="true">

<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

<cache name="loadstatus"
maxEntriesLocalHeap = "10000"
maxEntriesLocalDisk= "100000"
eternal = "false"
diskSpoolBufferSizeMB = "20"
timeToIdleSeconds="28800" timeToLiveSeconds="28800"
memoryStoreEvictionpolicy ="LFU"`enter code here`
transactionalMode ="off">
<persistance strategy = "localTempSwap"/>
</cache>       
</ehcache>
```

service class

```
@Service
public class ServiceImplementation {

@Autowired
ClientImplementation webServiceClient;

@Cacheable(value = "loadstatus")    
public List<GetLoadStatusResonseElement> getLoadStatus() throws Exception{
List<GetLoadStatusResonseElement> list = null;
list = webServiceClient.getLoadStatus();
return list;
}
}
```

PS: Data coming from web service into my method loadstatus need to be refreshed every 24 hr. But for the same day data will remain same, So for a particular day I want to cache the output of the web service.

Answer (score 0):

Just specifying `@Cacheable` is not enough. You also need to tell Spring that is should look for those annotations.

Adding `<cache:annotation-driven/>` should fix it (and of course, you need to add the correspondig xsd)

Comment: I have mentioned that in my code but forgt to mention it here.